# Make command on Kubuntu device

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have to compile a source code to get the executables. However, the make command fails to compile due to the presence of a parantheses with the following error message:

```
sh: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
Makefile: 36: recipe for target 'dynamic' failed
make[1]: [dynamic] Error 2
```

I visited the Makefile which I attach to this post:

```
# get PETSC_DIR, PETSC_ARCH and MPIHOME from NEMO 5 build system
#LIBMESH_VERSION = 0.8.0
include ../../make.inc

#all: libmesh/configure static dynamic
all: libmesh/configure dynamic
# <ss 12/09/10> static stuff is only needed on jaguar

libmesh/configure:
@echo "Extracting libmesh-$(LIBMESH_VERSION).tar.gz..."
tar zxf libmesh-$(LIBMESH_VERSION).tar.gz

# <ss 17.7.2010> PETSc now is mandatory for libmesh - however, libmesh takes MPI configuration from petsc configuration files in that case.
# libmesh searches for $PETSC_DIR/include/petsc.h and needs $PETSC_ARCH to be set
# On nanohub, things got messed up and OpenMIP libraries linked to executables. to prevent this, I had to disable VTK within libmesh.
# <ss 13.8.2010> disabled tetgen because libtetgen.a seems to contain an int main() which makes static linking impossible. 
# Note: the 'make clean' before 'make all' for the contributions is mandatory, otherwise shared LASPACK will not compile.

static: libmesh/configure
@echo "###########################################"
@echo "#                                         #"
@echo "# Configuring Libmesh (STATIC libraries)  #"
@echo "#                                         #"
@echo "###########################################"
(export libmesh_CXXFLAGS=$(libmesh_CXXFLAGS) ; \
export libmesh_INCLUDE=$(libmesh_INCLUDE); \
export SLEPC_DIR=$(SLEPC_DIR); \
cd libmesh; ./configure PETSC_DIR=$(PETSC_REAL_BUILD) MPIHOME=$(MPIHOME) PETSC_ARCH=$(PETSC_REAL_ARCH) \
F77="$(MPIF77)" CC="$(MPICC)" GCC="$(GCC)" CXX="$(MPICXX)"  --enable-vtk --with-vtk-include=$(VTKINC_PATH) \
--with-vtk-lib=$(VTKLIB_PATH) --disable-tetgen --disable-tecplot \
--disable-nemesis --disable-shared --enable-parmesh  --enable-amr; \
make clean; make; \
cd contrib; make clean; make all)

dynamic: libmesh/configure
@echo "###########################################"
@echo "#                                         #"
@echo "# Configuring Libmesh (DYNAMIC libraries) #"
@echo "#                                         #"
@echo "###########################################"
(export libmesh_CXXFLAGS=$(libmesh_CXXFLAGS); \
export libmesh_CPPFLAGS=$(libmesh_CPPFLAGS); \
export libmesh_INCLUDE=$(libmesh_INCLUDE); \
export METHODS=(opt,dbg);\
export SLEPC_DIR=$(SLEPC_DIR)/build-real; \
cd libmesh; ./configure PETSC_DIR=$(PETSC_REAL_BUILD) MPIHOME=$(MPIHOME) PETSC_ARCH=$(PETSC_REAL_ARCH) \
F77="$(MPIF77)" CC="$(MPICC)" GCC="$(GCC)" CXX="$(MPICXX)" --enable-vtk  --with-vtk-include=$(VTKINC_PATH) \
--with-vtk-lib=$(VTKLIB_PATH) --disable-tetgen --enable-triangle --enable-slepc  --disable-nemesis --disable-cxx11 --disable-strict-lgpl \
--enable-parmesh --enable-amr --enable-shared=yes --disable-glibcxx-debugging ; \
make clean; make --jobs=4; \
cd contrib; make clean; make all --jobs=4;)

clean:
    cd libmesh; make clean

distclean:
    rm -rf libmesh
```

I think the problem is about forcing to use the bash shell as I read from other posts. I did so but it didn't work.
I run it using Kubuntu: KDE version of Ubuntu.
Many thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The formatting of the apparent `Makefile` is not correct. Is there a tab missing on most lines which don't end with a colon?

Comment: The error seems vaguely like the `Makefile` author expected `SHELL=/bin/bash` but you are running it with `SHELL=/bin/sh`

Comment: @tripleee that’s exactly what I am afraid of! I introduced SHELL := /bin/bash at the beginning of this make file but still giving out messages in the sh environment.

Comment: @tripleee regarding the tab thing maybe some spaces have to be added here and there during the posting process but before the stated point the code seems to compile well

Comment: Syntax errors in the code you are posting should be removed if they are not in the original, if only so as not to obscure the real problem

Comment: @tripleee I confirm the real problem is the syntax error I posted. Just recently I checked through remote connection: The default shell is bash through echo $0 command but as seen: the message comes from an sh shell! Could it be because it is “subshelled” into an sh shell?

Comment: We have no idea what the dependent Makefiles called by this one actually do. Quite possibly they hard-code `/bin/sh` or just inherit `SHELL` from something whose default is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: https://github.com/libMesh/libmesh/blob/b4f26309dd7daf29c7ce2bd0147cf2eb0b09f996/m4/libmesh_method.m4 looks like it actually wants the methods in a string, separated by whitespace. [The README.md](https://github.com/libMesh/libmesh/blob/8a0da5d9743db31b17141d2abc9c5049da990ada/README.md#methods) seems to corroborate this. But I'm not sure if this is even the same project as the one you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The project's `README.md`](https://github.com/libMesh/libmesh/blob/8a0da5d9743db31b17141d2abc9c5049da990ada/README.md#methods) looks like you should have used

```
../configure --with-methods="opt dbg"
```

(without parentheses, whitespace separated) and not (apparently) `../configure --with-methods="(opt,dbg)"`

Comment: thanks that has solved the problem although the make is not working yet because of another problem regarding a subsequent make file

Answer (score 1):

Check line 4 of the dynamic target, as the error message states:

```
export METHODS=(opt,dbg);\
```

should probably be something else, or the part (opt,dbg) should be in double-quotes:

```
export METHODS="(opt,dbg)";\
```

Comment: Thanks @marcolz this is part of a bigger simulation program that used to work well on earlier Linux versions. Would this command change over time from an earlier to a recent version of the shell script? I have to test this thing tomorrow

Comment: It depends on whether the later parts of the script (somewhere deep inside another `configure` -generated build file, apparently) expects `METHODS` to contain a Bash array (in which case this needs to run under `bash`) or just a static string (in which case adding the quotes is the correct thing to do, but probably would never have worked correctly with earlier versions of (k)Ubuntu).